# Qual a melhor forma de selecionar um texto e como armazená-lo em uma variavel?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Preciso copiar um texto e estou utilizando o **pyautogui**. Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de selecionar o texto e como armazenar essa informação em uma variável?

A solução que encontrei, até o momento, para o primeiro problema, foi apertar o <kbd>shift</kbd> e clicar no ponto final do texto. Para o segundo, ainda estou aprendendo.

Segue o código.

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.leftClick(1218,1051)
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.leftClick(82,68)
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Comment: Veja o `hotkey`. Algo como: `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')` para copiar e `pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')` para colar.

Comment: Como não foi dito de onde você está tentando tirar o texto, vou dar uma sugestão mais segura caso seja de página web. Faça o Web Scraping, é uma forma mais sadia e segura para sua aplicação. Caso possa nos dar mais informações, eu posso tentar ajudar de outra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Bom como você já consegue copiar o texto, da para usar a biblioteca `clipboard`  junto com o  `PyAutoGui` para executar a função.

Pode ser usado assim:

```
import clipboard
import pyautogui

pyautogui.doubleClick(x, y) # ou na sua solução pressionar shift e clicar
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
texto = clipboard.paste()
clipboard.copy("") # caso queira deixar vazia após settar a variavel.
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Se esse texto estiver em uma espécie de `textbox`, onde o cursor fica parecendo o número 1 romano, você pode clicar nessa área e usar o <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> (selecionar tudo), depois copiar com o <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>.